# Why does "undefined equals false" return false?

Tags: javascript

When I compare undefined and null against Boolean false, the statement returns false:

```
undefined == false;
null == false;
```

It return false. Why?

Comment: Why would you expect it to be true?

Comment: Because `false` is a valid boolean value.  Whereas `undefined` and `null` are not.  So they're not equal.

Comment: i mean undefined is also false so false == false return true.

Comment: @SLaks Because `0 == false` is true, etc.

Comment: @abdulraziq: `"i mean undefined is also false"` - No it's not.  It's `undefined`.

Comment: BTW, you should use strict equality.

Comment: @WesleyMurch ok removing my comment.

Comment: @Mr_Green that confused me even more

Comment: @abdulraziq forget it.. think it as nightmare.. :)

Comment: To illustrate the difference between `false` and `undefined`... I have 3 apples. I give 3 apples to Jane. Do I have any apples left? (false)  Do I have any oranges left? (undefined)

Comment: If you think about it, in practical terms, `undefined` and `false` aren't equivalent. Say you have an object with a property which will be set to `true` or `false`, but only once an external network call has been made to confirm which value is appropriate. In this case, if this property is undefined, that means the network call hasn't returned yet; it doesn't mean that the property's value can be considered to be `false`.

Comment: See http://www.mapbender.org/JavaScript_pitfalls:_null,_false,_undefined,_NaN for an explanation of all this Javascript magic.

Comment: I like this article: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Comment: in if condition if i put undefined its works as expected so why its not working in comparison ?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Sure `0 == false`, but `0 != null` and `0 != undefined` either?

Comment: Undefined and false aren't equivalent but JS is truthy/falsey making that irrelevant. If I create a new, empty object `var obj = {}`, it appears contradictory that `obj.fakeProp == false` is `false` while `!obj.fakeProp` is `true`. I would expect `obj.fakeProp == false` to evaluate to true and `obj.fakeProp === false` to evaluate to false.

Answer (score 46):

With the original answer pointing to the spec being deleted, I'd like to provide a link and short excerpt from the spec here.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

The ECMA spec doc lists the reason that `undefined == false` returns false. Although it does not directly say why this is so, the most important part in answering this question lies in this sentence:

```
The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false.
```

If we look up the definition for null, we find something like this:

```
NULL or nil means "no value" or "not applicable".
```

In Javascript, `undefined` is treated the same way. It is without any value. However, false does have a value. It is telling us that something is not so. Whereas `undefined` and `null` are not supposed to be giving any value to us. Likewise, there is nothing it can convert to for its abstract equality comparison therefore the result would always be false. It is also why `null == undefined` returns true (They are both without any value). It should be noted though that `null === undefined` returns false because of their different types. (Use `typeof(null)` and `typeof(undefined)` in a console to check it out)

What I'm curious of though, is that comparing `NaN` with anything at all will **always** return false. Even when comparing it to itself. [`NaN == NaN` returns false]

Also, another odd piece of information: [`typeof NaN` returns "number"]

---

### Strict Equality

If possible, you should avoid using the == operator to compare two values. Instead use === to truly see if two values are equal to each other. == gives the illusion that two values really are exactly equal when they may not be by using coercion.  Examples:

`5 == "5"` is true

`5 === "5"` is false

`"" == false` is true

`"" === false` is false

`0 == false` is true

`0 === false` is false

Comment: The best part of [that specs link](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) is that `undefined == null` is true **only because the spec specifically says so**! "_2. If_ x _is **null** and_ y _is **undefined**, return **true**.
3. If_ x _is **undefined** and_ y _is **null**, return **true**._" So it's not only b/c of loose vs. strict equality, it's also ontological -- the spec says they're loosely equivalent so they're loosely equivalent/coerce to `false` here! There's nothing inherent about `undefined` & `null` that coerce them to `false` when compared against one another.

Answer (score 1):

[From the incomparable MDN, sponsored by the company of JavaScript's creator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

> JavaScript provides three different value-comparison operations:
>
> - strict equality (or "triple equals" or "identity") using ===,
> - loose equality ("double equals") using ==,
> - and Object.is (new in ECMAScript > 6).
>
> The choice of which operation to use depends on what sort of
> comparison you are looking to perform.
>
> Briefly, double equals will perform a type conversion when comparing
> two things; triple equals
> will do the same comparison without type conversion (by simply always
> returning false if the types differ); and Object.is will behave the
> same way as triple equals, but with special handling for NaN and -0
> and +0 so that the last two are not said to be the same, while
> Object.is(NaN, NaN) will be true. (Comparing NaN with NaN
> ordinarily—i.e., using either double equals or triple equals—evaluates
> to false, because IEEE 754 says so.) Do note that the distinction
> between these all have to do with their handling of primitives; none
> of them compares whether the parameters are conceptually similar in
> structure. For any non-primitive objects x and y which have the same
> structure but are distinct objects themselves, all of the above forms
> will evaluate to false.

For a visual overview of the whole picture of equality in JavaScript:
https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

The truth is, this seemingly "bad" aspect of JavaScript is a source of power when you understand how it works.

Comment: No, MDN isn't created by a company. Those articles are written by arbitrary volunteers, it's a wiki :-)

Comment: @Bergi I'm well aware of who contributes to MDN. MDN itself is created by Mozilla though. If you're going to be pedantic, get it right.

Answer (score 0):

So undefined really means undefined. Not False, not True, not 0, not empty string. So when you compare undefined to *anything*, the result is always false, it is *not* equal to that.

Comment: `undefined == null` is true.

Comment: Wow, @SLaks. Appears so, and I was surprised, and kind of disappointed. Read up and appears that it is because the "==" operator can do coercion between the two. Agree with Xander that the "===" Does not do and to me is more"intuitive". Glad you brought up, learned something myself today!

Comment: @asantaballa null == undefined because it is defined to be so: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: Always use === when possible in JavaScript. == gives the illusion that two values really are exactly equal when they may not be. (5 == "5" is true. 5 === "5" is false.)

Answer (score -1):

You question is half, as we compare undefined/ null to any other types.
we will have false return.
There is no coercion happening, even we are using == operator.

Answer (score -2):

Undefined is not the same thing as false, `false` is a boolean object (which has a value of 0 therefore it is indeed defined).

An example:

```
var my_var;
var defined = (my_var === undefined)
alert(defined);  //prints true.  It is true that my_var is undefined

my_var = 22;
defined = (my_var === undefined)
alert(defined);  //prints false.  my_var is now defined

defined = (false === undefined)
alert(defined);  //prints false, false is defined

defined = (true === undefined)
alert(defined);  //prints false, true is defined
```

Comment: @WesleyMurch also == !== ===.

Comment: But `!undefined == true` is true :)

Comment: @vp_arth my favorite is `undefined == null` and `undefined !== null` (both of which are true)

Answer (score -2):

This is so because it is so. :)

Read the ECMA standards here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: If you are going to link to a standard, link to the official one: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: Find you any difference before downvoting?

Comment: Other than the fact that your link is older by two years (yours is from 2009, mine is from 2011), what does your link and response add that my link/explanation (posted 14 minutes before this) omitted?

Comment: @SoulEc I don't see it while search through my bookmarks, sorry. Is this a real problem? what should I do?

Comment: if you aren't adding anything to the discussion, it's better to just remove your answer.

Comment: Oh, really? Why? is it wrong? Is it less concise? Your answer is right too, I upvote it and wish you it be accepted

Comment: I've experienced frustrations in the past where the first result for a google search is an SO answer was a link-only answer for an expired link or a "read the spec" answer.  Worst experience ever.  I don't know who is running ecma262-5.com (seems like a guy just paying for hosting), but I do know that ecma-international.org is actually run by an organization with funds

Answer (score -2):

According to the [specification flow](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3):

> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x ==
> ToNumber(y).

```
1) undefined == false; -> undefined == Number(false); -> undefined == 0;
2) null == false; -> null == Number(false); -> null == 0;
```

There is no rule for these cases, so go with the behavior in the last step:

> Return false.

Comment: `ToNumber` is never called on `undefined`. Not sure where you got that from.

Comment: It is from specification, so I just got it from here. If you have something specific to say, go ahead.

Comment: I say that you misread or misunderstood the specification. Btw, it would be nice to link that document you are citing.

Comment: Both
`If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).`
and
`If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.`

I have got from the [spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).

I don't see specifically written in it what you have posted that `ToNumber` is never called on `undefined`.

Comment: Well "*If Type(y) is Boolean*" doesn't apply when `y` is `undefined`. The steps that you are quoting do apply `ToNumber` to the boolean value, not the `undefined` value.