# In if statement,undefined equals with false

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined

I'm confused with the code below:

```
if(undefined){
   //code will not be executed
}
```

and

```
if(!undefined){
   //code will be executed
}
```

Is that mean the "undefined" equals with false?

Here [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277458/why-does-undefined-equals-false-return-false/37167227#37167227) related,but no one point above situation out.

Comment: The truthy value of `undefined` in Javascript is `false`. Hence the behaviour that you see.

Comment: `Boolean(undefined)` is `false`.but  your comments should be interchanged

Comment: @FastSnail Is that means if statement will switch every parameter passed to it inside?I mean,just like this:` if(Boolean(parameter)){//code}`,right?

Comment: @XheldonCao if you pass a none Boolean value then yes.javascript use `Boolean()` function to get a boolean value because if condition need a boolean value

Comment: @FastSnail Now I know,thanks guys!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It means that `undefined` is a falsy value, list of falsy values are:

```
""        // Empty string
null      // null
undefined // undefined, which you get when doing: var a;
false     // Boolean false
0         // Number 0
NaN       // Not A Number eg: "a" * 2
```

If you negate a falsy value you will get true:

```
!""        === true
!null      === true
!undefined === true
!0         === true
!NaN       === true
```

And when you nagate a truthy value you will get false:

```
!"hello" === false
!1       === false
```

But `undefined` is not equal `false`:

```
undefined === false // false
undefined  == false // false
```

And just for the fun if it:

```
undefined == null // true
```

Comment: I am shocked that `undefined == false` gives `false`! How come? Where I can read about it?

Comment: @Marecky there is a nice write up on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: is it safe to use undefined to test for falsey this way? is `if (company.list_of_buildings) {` as good as: `if (Array.isArray(company.list_of_buildings) && company.list_of_buildings.length) {` ??

Comment: @Zaffer The later ensures that `company.list_of_buildings` is an array with at least one item in it, while the other just ensures that `company.list_of_buildings` is non falsy, which means it could be a string, non zero number among other things.

Answer (score 7):

In javascript strict mode, `undefined` is not false, but javascript try to convert the object or var to a `boolean` value (this is called in javascript **truthy value**), that's the reason you got an `undefined` as false. This happens with null also, for example.

You can force that with this strict no equality:

```
if(undefined!==false) console.log("Is not false");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look below checked falsy values:

```
""==false?
    Ans: true
null == false?
    Ans: false
undefined == false?
    Ans: false
0 == false?
    Ans: true
NaN == false?
    Ans: false
null == NaN?
    Ans: false
```

We can see that `null == false`,`undefined == false`,`null == NaN`, and `NaN == false` are not `true`
That means they are not equal. From the above result, we got 3 falsy values group:

1. The False group
2. The Null group and
3. The NaN group

But a negative falsy value is always true:

```
!""        === true
!null      === true
!undefined === true
!0         === true
!NaN       === true
```

For example:
To check `true` value of `dataTitle` variable

```
if(dataTitle && (dataTitle != null))
{
    console.log('hi');
}
```

The above statement will check the false group as well as the null group

To check `false` value of `dataTitle` variable

```
if(!dataTitle)
{
    console.log('hi');
}

//or 

if(dataTitle==null || dataTitle===false)
  console.log('hi');
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `undefined` and `null` are empty properties declared on the global scope.
Their value doesn't equal `false`; they both have the initial value of primitive [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/undefined).

```
undefined == false // false
```

With that said, both will result in `false` value upon a programmatic true/false evaluation. In your example, you used a [logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) operator (MDN):

> Returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true

The negation operator first evaluated `undefined` as `false`, and then negated the value to `true`. You can illustrate the process roughly like this:

```
if (!(!!undefined)) {
    // code will be executed
}
```