# Why undefined is not equal to zero in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm discovering odds of JavaScript comparisons. I wanted to find an example of how tricky comparisons may be, and how can cause bugs in some situations.

I thought about example where some input variable remains undefined, and is compared to zero. Because undefined is false when converted to Boolean, and zero is false when converted to Boolean I decided to test following code:

```
var x;
//Here x should be initialized but due to some circumstances is not
if(x == 0){
   //This should run
}
```

Surprisingly...

```
Boolean(undefined) //false
Boolean(0) //false
x //undefined
x == 0 //false
```

Why it's like that?

Comment: Since `1` and `2` are both truthy, would you expect `1 == 2` to be `true`?

Comment: What sort of answer are you expecting beyond "because the spec says so"? http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: Well `undefined != 0` and I guess that's just how it is. See there for the complete list of JS comparisons: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: Basically the same reasoning as [Why does “undefined equals false” return false?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19277458/215552)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This behaviour is in the specification for [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

From the specification

The comparison `x == y`, where `x` and `y` are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:

1. If `Type(x)` is the same as `Type(y)`, then ...
   ...
2. If `x` is null and `y` is undefined, return true.
3. **If `x` is undefined and `y` is `null`, return true.**
4. If `Type(x)` is Number and `Type(y)` is String, return the result of the `comparison x == ToNumber(y)`.
5. If `Type(x)` is String and `Type(y)` is Number, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.
6. If `Type(x)` is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.
7. If `Type(y)` is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.
8. If `Type(x)` is either String or Number and `Type(y)` is Object, return the result of the `comparison x == ToPrimitive(y)`.
9. If `Type(x)` is Object and `Type(y)` is either String or Number, return the result of the comparison `ToPrimitive(x) == y`.
10. Return false.

As `undefined` and a number *(`0`)* is not of the same type, it's only in the third point where it mentions what to do if the left hand side is `undefined`.
Then, if the right hand side is `null`, it returns true, any other value, and it goes straight to `10.`, which says "`return false`".

Comment: Wow! That's amazing. If I'd compare undefined variable to any variable with already "known type" (so to speak) would it try to convert undefined to that type?

Comment: @Landeeyo - actually no, it's a bit more complicated, the specification has the answer to this, and I posted a bit hasty, let me edit.

Comment: This part of specification is stunning. Great answer. Thank you a lot!

Comment: So in other words, comparing two "falsy" values of different type doesn't always return true, especially when the first value is `undefined`, then the only right hand value that is of an other type, and that would return true, is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Boolean(undefined) //false
Boolean(0) //false
```

Actually, The `Boolean` function returns `false` for all non-real values such as 0, null, undefined, ""(empty string), etc.

It does not mean that the `undefined == 0`