# Why is undefined not falsey in Array.prototype.filter?

Tags: javascript

I made an error in the predicate I passed to filter and got a curious result. I of course should have written `emp.gender === "F"`. Nevertheless, given that `undefined` is falsey, I would have expected `femaleEmployees` to be an empty array. However, it includes all the members of the original array.

```
var employees = [
  { name: "bob", gender: "M" },
  { name: "lisa", gender: "F" },
  { name: "vera", gender: "F" }
];
var femaleEmployees = employees.filter(emp => emp.gender = "F");
```

I suspect it has something to do with this, but I'm not entirely sure how: [Why does "undefined equals false" return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277458/why-does-undefined-equals-false-return-false)

Comment: sure you don't have a typo there?  In your post it reads `emp.gender = "F"`. That's no check

Comment: `emp.gender = "F"` that's always true ("F" is truthly). You are assigning a variable, you probably wanted to compare it instead.

Comment: Returned value in each iteration is "F" which is true.

Comment: Where is `undefined` in this? I don't see any.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Ah, my mistake. I thought the predicate returned undefined, not F.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` or `===` to compare the values instead of assigning symbol `=`. A non-empty string is a truthy value so the result includes all the elements since it always returning `"F"` which is truthy( ie, you are updating `gender` property as `"F"` and then returning the property value which is `"F"` ).

```
var femaleEmployees = employees.filter(emp => emp.gender === "F");
```

Refer : [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)